# kafka console consumer throws auth SecurityProtocol error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kerberos

I have enabled Kerberos for Kafka. I am able to produce the data using below command

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list HOSTNAME:6667 --topic test --producer-property security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

But while consuming I am facing error like below

> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka
>   consumer

I am using below command to consume

```
/usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server HOSTNAME:6667 --topic test --consumer-property security.protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify set `security.protocol` to use SASL then you need to also specify:

- `sasl.jaas.config`: to provide the SASL credentials
- `sasl.mechanism`: to select the SASL mechanism, Kafka supports `GSSAPI` (Kerberos), `PLAIN`, `SCRAM-SHA-256`, `SCRAM-SHA-512` and `OAUTHBEARER`

See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_plain_clientconfig for details about these settings.

Comment: I have tried with Java API it is working. while using Kafka console only I am facing above error

Comment: Now it is also working. the issue is I didn't mention '='  after security. protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT   Actual command is   /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server HOSTNAME:6667 --topic test --consumer-property security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT